# Does someone know how to convert Facebook.Json to set of the understandable C# objects?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am fed up investigate how to convert Facebook.Json stuff to some C# classes.

Any clue if there is some open source ready-to-use solution for all entities of Facebook?

Just to parse posts to some `List<Post>` or something like that??

Thank you!

```
dynamic p = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(userID + "/posts");

        foreach (dynamic value in p.Values) 
        {
            Post post = new Post();
            foreach (dynamic item in value)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best C# .NET books?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-sharp-net-books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own set of objects and write a custom deserializer?

Do FB not have a C# SDK?

Comment: To do it I need the complete description of all Facebook entities which we can get via Graph API. But I guess we don't have it or I am wrong?

Comment: I think they have actually - http://www.facebook.com/csharpsdk Never used it so can't comment on its completeness or usefulness..

Comment: All the entities will exist within the SDK will they not?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) - it's Linq namespace has some objects that you can use to dynamically access JSON formatted data.  If you want strongly typed objects, the JsonConvert class will deserialize JSON data easily into your own classes also.